# NetBeans Java Calculator Query

Tags: java, netbeans, calculator, helper

I'm having a small problem that is when im multiplying for example 5*5 the answer will be 25. But when multiplying 5*5*5 the answer will still stay 25.. Help?

The Variables

```
public class Calculator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double total;
    double input;

    boolean plus = false;
    boolean multi = false;
    boolean division = false;
    boolean minus = false;
}
```

The Multiply button

```
private void btnMultiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    input = Double.parseDouble(txtArea.getText());

    total = input;
    multi = true;
    txtArea.setText(null);
}
```

The Equals Button

```
private void btnEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    if (plus == true )
    {
        input = Double.parseDouble(txtArea.getText());    
        total = input + total;        
    }
    else if (minus == true)
    {
        input = Double.parseDouble(txtArea.getText());        
        total = input - total;
    }
    else if (multi == true)
    {
        input = Double.parseDouble(txtArea.getText());        
        total = input * total;
    }
    else if (division == true)
    {
        input = Double.parseDouble(txtArea.getText());        
        total = input / total;
    } 
    else
    {
    }

    txtArea.setText("" +total);


}
```

Comment: You need nested multiplication or use ScriptEngine.eval operatoin.

Comment: I am unable to find the place... where you are doing 5*5*5... as else if (multi == true)
    {
        input = Double.parseDouble(txtArea.getText());        
        total = input * total;
    } 
only reflects the multiplication but not any 5*5*5...

Comment: You are doing right may be some UI issue. Update your complete code in your question.

Comment: Did you tried my answer... Mr. user2964786

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the input (`5*5`) as `Double`, which gets as result `5`, because `*5` is not part of the `Double`.

Then you assign `input` to `total`. Then you multiply `input` with `total`, resulting in 25.

Your logic is exactly doing what it is told to do, however you want to really calculate something. That is going to be more difficult.

In the case of `5*5*5` your `input` will again be just `5`.

I've explained why `5*5 = 25` and `5*5*5 = 25` for your program.

The solution would be to make some kind of parsing engine which translates like this:

- `5*5` to `mul(5, 5)`
- `5*5*5` to `mul(5, mul(5, 5))`

And then have the Java operations behind it to really calculate it.

Comment: he is not parsing 5*5, read the code well. each time perform an action he clears the txt area

Comment: @vels4j So he parses `5` the first time, and then all `input` is magically gone. I think I've said that, correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: **You are parsing the input (5*5) as Double, which gets as result 5** This is wrong can not parse string 5*5. Assume like doing operation in calculator. Press 5 -> Press * -> Press 5 -> Press =

Comment: @vels4j I think he is using a `JTextArea` and has a `JButton` for calculating the result. Atleast that is what his code suggests. So it seems like he is parsing the whole `JTextArea.getText()` in once.

Comment: **he is parsing the whole JTextArea.getText()** yes but each operation he clears text area. text area never have a text like 5*5

Answer (score 0):

Your function `private void btnMultiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` is resetting textarea every time... so whenever you will call it, it will only cater a single value and will not cater the old result...
Eliminate the following line from this function and check... I guess it will solve the issue

```
txtArea.setText(null);
```

and if you need to reset text area every time then consider the following solution...

**Solution:**

**Step 1:** At the time of declaration of the variable `total`, you need to initialize it with 0.0 as well.

**Step 2:** Apply the following check on your statement i.e. `total = input;` in `btnMultiActionPerformed` function.

***Check:***

```
if (total > 0.0)
            total = total * input;
        else
            total = input;
```

This will definitely do the job for you.

***Dangling Pointer***

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the unchecked assignment in **btnMultiActionPerformed** method.

```
total = input;
```

Due to this, each time Multiply button is clicked, the old result gets lost.
Check assignment should be performed as follows:

```
private void btnMultiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            input = Double.parseDouble(txtArea.getText());
            //perform check below, instead of unchecked assignment
            if (total == 0)
                total = input;
            else
                total *= input;
            multi = true;
            txtArea.setText(null);
        }
```

Comment: This solution will faulter, consider the scenario where user has come to the application first time... then total will not be equal to zero, as it is not initialized and then it will go in the else part where total will be multiplied with input and stored in total... Which will cause unstable and unwanted result.

Comment: @DanglingPointer: you are wrong, it will never faulter because in Java, double is initialised to zero by default, please refer [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Comment: Ok... But it is initialized by 0.0 as it is a double value, not 0.

Comment: @DanglingPointer: Again you are wrong, Java has [Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) `If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.` Also refer [== Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1). Good luck with Java

Comment: I didnt said that it will produce any error... but after reading that above mentioned link... I wrote the comment and yes... the if condition will be satisfied with either of 0 or 0.0...

Comment: @DanglingPointer your comment started with `but`, so if you are not expecting an error, then what did you expect and refer to in your comment? I hope the links helped clear doubts.